# Зачем использовать PUT и DELETE methods в Laravel, если можно GET?

Tags: php, laravel, get

Делаю todo приложение и для удаления записей столкнулся с такой реализацией:

```php
// Blade
<span onclick="event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById('form-delete-{{$todo->id}}')
            .submit();" 
      class="fas fa-trash px-2 text-red-500 cursor-pointer"></span>

<form style="display: none;" 
      id="{{'form-delete-'.$todo->id}}" 
      method="post" 
      action="{{route('todo.delete', $todo->id)}}">
    @csrf
    @method('delete')
</form>
```

```php
// Route
Route::delete('/todos/{todo}/delete', 'App\Http\Controllers\TodoController@delete')
->name('todo.delete');
```

Все вполне себе работает, **но зачем писать столько кода в `blade`, когда можно сделать так:**

```php
// Blade
<a href="{{route('todo.delete', $todo->id)}}" class="text-red-500 
                                                     cursor-pointer 
                                                     text-white">
    <span class="fas fa-trash px-2"></span>
</a>
```

```php
// Route
Route::get('/todos/{todo}/delete', 'App\Http\Controllers\TodoController@delete')
->name('todo.delete');
```

И все также прекрасно работает! Контроллер не стал вставлять, там всего 1 банальная строчка удаления записи.
Всё что я сделал в Route, так это поменял метод с `delete` на `get`. Теперь в `blade` файле все смотрится куда лаконичнее.

Но в таком случае удаление записи делается посредством `get` и вроде как это не правильно...
Какие могут быть последствия такой "хитрости" и почему так неправильно делать? ...Или, все таки тоже правильно?

Comment: Ага. До первого пришедшего бота гугла который пройдёт по всем ссылкам и удалит все ваши тудушки.

Comment: Или префетча фейсбука и т.п. в общем правило опасные запросы не должны выполнятся методом GET написаны не зря

Comment: Другое дело что вовсе не обязательно это делать при помощи дополнительной формы. Можно и просто post-запрос отправить при помощи fetch()

Answer (score 0):

Все правильно, что работает)
Есть определенные стандарты и методологи, и REST одна из них.
Следовать ей или нет ваше дело, но при работе с командой лучше использовать придерживаться одной архитектуры, иначе тогда каждый начнет писать как хочет и начнется бардак.

`Так то по сути и сахар можно держать в солонке, только вовремя другим сказать))`